# Prove Limit of Functions Is Measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[image]

I am not sure how to how a sequence of functions is measurable. Furthermore, the question does not specify the interval over which $f_n$ is measurable (Is it correct to make the function measurable over $\mathbb{R}$?)

Answer (score 1):

Your notices in your picture are hard to read !

Since $x_n \to x$, we have $f_m(x)=\frac{mx}{1+mx^2}$ for  $x \in \mathbb R$.

If $x=0$, then $f(0) = \lim_{m \to \infty}f_m(0)=0$ and for $x \ne 0$ we have

$f(x) = \lim_{m \to \infty}f_m(x)=1/x$.

There is only one point $x_0$ in $ \mathbb R$ such that $f$ is not continuous in $x_0$:  $x_0=0$.

Hence $f$ is measurable.